# How to get / output all days in the current week in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: weekday, automationanywhere

I'm attempting to output all days within the current week. e.g. for this week, show all days, 05/12/2019 through 05/18/2019 only. when the bot is executed next week, only show days 05/19/2019 through 05/25/2019. My current logic outputs the days for this week, but come tomorrow, the dates for this week will be thrown off. Please see the following

[image]

...could I get some help with this please?

Comment: Could you explain this part "but come tomorrow, the dates for this week will be thrown off."?

Comment: @KhaledMostafaMe ... sure, yesterday, my dates for the current week were displaying Sunday as 05/12/19, Monday as 05/13/19 correctly along with the remaining days of the current week. But, today my dates are off by 1, for example, Monday for this week is now showing 05/14/19 instead of 05/13/19. ...any suggestions? –

Comment: I think it's not possible through Automation Anywhere, you will have to do it using VBS or Metabot. I prefer the VBS method, Which one do you prefer?

Comment: @KhaledMostafaMe Given that I'm not allowed to use external scripts, I would have to use the Metabot approach. could you help me with that?

Comment: Well updated, check the answer again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using VBS

I would do this using a VBS script, using **Run Script** command.

The default week start is Sunday you can change it check: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_weekday.asp

Pass the day you that you want as a parameter from 0 to 6, and get the data as a return value.

DayNumber: `0 = Sunday ..... 6 = Saturday`

```
InputDate = Date
DayNumber = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
Result = DateAdd("d", DayNumber - WeekDay(InputDate, 2), InputDate)
WScript.StdOut.Write(Result)
'MsgBox(Result)
```

---

### Using MetaBot

**Metabot Link:** [Change Date and Time Format](https://botstore.automationanywhere.com/bot/change-date-and-time-format/)

You will have to run the following logic in sequence.

**Input:** DayNumber: `0 = Sunday ..... 6 = Saturday`

1. Using **DayOfWeek** Logic, Get the Day of the week and assign it to
   **WeekDay** variable, it will return the name, not the number, and the input will be Date.
2. Using IF conditions convert the name of
   the day to number, start from 0 to 6 as your first day in the week,
   which is Sunday, and using variable operation assigns the value to
   **NumWeekDay** variable.
3. Using variable operation, Get the offset by subtracting **DayNumber**, the day you want minus **NumWeekDay**,
   and assign the value to **Offset** variable.
4. Using AddDays, Input
   the date and the offset, and you will get the date of the day that you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I greatly appreciate your help